# kombu producer and celery consumer

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, kombu

Is it possible for a kombu producer to queue a message on rabbitmq to be processed by celery workers? It seems the celery workers do not understand the message put by the kombu producer.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that to communicate with RabbitMQ, you would require any lib that abides by AMQP specification. 
Kombu is one such lib which can bind to the RabbitMQ exchange, listen and process messages by spawning numerous consumers.
Celery is nothing but an asynchronous task generator which has numerous add-ons like in-memory processing, capacity to write to DB/Redis cache, perform complex operations and so on.
Said that now you can use kombu to read and write messages in/from RMQ and use celery workers to process the message.

Answer (score 0):

Celery worker to process message need a more info.
Task name, id in headers and so on.